# Install Linux from Linux

Tags: linux, system-installation

I recently purchased an external USB hard drive and wanted to use it as a portable boot drive. I installed Linux Mint 18.1 on it and got everything working.

Then I started to think about using that drive to install Linux on other machines. I assumed that whatever a live boot USB does should be possible from a full-blown Linux installation. I looked around and the only option I found was from Ubuntu: [Installation/From Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux). Their solution is to create a partition, fill it with the ISO contents and then boot from that to launch the installer.
I did follow those instructions and got it working as expected, however, I still feel there must be a way to install Linux from Linux without booting into an ISO.

I just found a related question: [Installing without booting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256895/228564). There is an answer there that suggests there is some sequence of operations that could be run to install Linux on another partition, but I would need more detail than provided there. Is that process documented somewhere?

Honestly, I would be more comfortable if I could just run the installers that are included in the live boot images of each distro. Or some kind of semi-authoritative script that would do the same thing. Is there a package in the repos that would provide such a thing (eg. a Linux Mint installer package that could be installed using `apt-get` or `yum`)?

Comment: I have no experience with that but I believe it this be referred to as a **bootstrap** install.

Comment: @phk Thank you. That is a good keyword to know. After seeing your comment, I remembered a part of the Ubuntu guide that I had ignored since the first method worked for me. It was about using the `debootstrap` utility to install. That looks to be the solution, will update after I try it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an example to install debian from a Linux-mint live USB (or any debian based distro). If you have a debian based distribution already installed on your hdd , you can install other debian based distro using `chroot` and `debootstrap` from the existing OS.

Boot from the live USB .Use gparted  to create your `root` , `swap` ,`/home`... partitions.

If you prefer the command line ( `fdisk` , parted ..) , there is how to activate the swap partition :

```
mkswap /dev/sdaY
sync
swapon /dev/sdaY
```

Let's say you need to install debian bullseye .

Install the `debootstrap` package :

```
sudo apt-get install debootstrap
```

Create the `/mnt/stable` then mount your root partition (`sdaX`)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/stable
sudo  mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/stable
```

Install the base system:

```
sudo debootstrap --arch amd64 bullseye /mnt/stable http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian
sudo mount -t proc none /mnt/stable/proc
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/stable/dev
sudo chroot /mnt/stable /bin/bash
```

Set up your root password:

```
passwd
```

Add a new user:

```
adduser your-username
```

Set up the hostname :

```
echo your_hostname > /etc/hostname
```

Configure the `/etc/fstab`:

add the following lines:

```
/dev/sdaX        /             ext4    defaults                 0    1
/dev/sdaY         none          swap    sw                      0    0
proc             /proc         proc    defaults                 0    0
```

use the [debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/SourcesList#Exemple_:_fichier_sources.list) to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Configure locale :

```
apt install locales
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Configure you keyboard:

```
apt install console-data
dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

Install the kernel:

```
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Then:

```
apt install linux-image-5.10.0-2-amd64
```

Configure the network:

```
editor /etc/network/interfaces
```

and past the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0 # replace eth0 with your interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0 # replace wlan0 with your interface
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

To manage the wifi network, install the following packages:

```
apt install iproute2 network-manager iw
```

Install grub :

```
apt install grub2
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

You can install a desktop environment through the command `tasksel` :

```
apt install aptitude tasksel
```

Run the following command and install your favourite GUI:

```
tasksel
```

Finally, exit the chroot and reboot your system

Documentation:  [D.3. Installing Debian GNU/Linux from a Unix/Linux System](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/apds03.html.en)

Debian wiki:

- [chroot](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot)
- [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap)

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you. I would just like to point out that this does not need to be done from a Live USB. This could be done from any Debian based Linux that is already running which is what I was looking for. (That may be what the parenthetical in your first sentence was getting at, I wasn't sure)

Comment: One thing I had to add to this: the old machine I was using to prep was BIOS, but the new machine I was prepping for was UEFI, so I had to use `refind-install --usedefault /dev/sda2` to get a bootloader installed.

Comment: I can't believe that debootstrap doesn't do all that for you. Chances that I remember all this stuff next time are zero.

Answer (score 0):

USB-creator does this for USB sticks.  I imagine it should be able to handle any removable media.

https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/usb-creator-gtk